# Modify indentation in ganttbar titles (pgfgantt package)

Tags: pgfgantt

I'm using the pgfgantt package to create a gantt chart but some links are overlapping with the titles of ganttbars. How Can I add some indentation to avoid this overlapping?

```
\begin{ganttchart}[hgrid, vgrid, x unit=0.8cm, y unit chart=0.7cm, title/.style={fill=blue!50, draw=none},
title label font=\color{white}\bfseries]{1}{10}
    \gantttitle{Cronograma de actividades semanales}{10} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,10}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup{Objetivo 1}{1}{1} \\
    \ganttbar{Actividad 1}{1}{1} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Actividad 2}{1}{1}\\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Actividad 3}{1}{1}\\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Actividad 4}{1}{1}
    \ganttnewline[thick, blue]
\end{ganttchart}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought arrows illustrated dependencies between tasks. Having arrows going backwards in time seems a little strange to me.

Anyway, I can think of two ways of preventing the overlapping labels:

**Option 1: make tasks consecutive in time**

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid, vgrid, x unit=0.8cm, y unit chart=0.7cm, 
title/.style={fill=blue!50, draw=none},
title label font=\color{white}\bfseries
]{1}{10}
    \gantttitle{Cronograma de actividades semanales}{10} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,10}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup{Objetivo 1}{1}{3} \\
    \ganttbar{Actividad 1}{1}{1} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Actividad 3}{2}{2}\\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Actividad 4}{3}{3}
    \ganttnewline[thick, blue]
\end{ganttchart}
```

[image]

**Option 2: offset labels**

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid, vgrid, x unit=0.8cm, y unit chart=0.7cm, 
title/.style={fill=blue!50, draw=none},
title label font=\color{white}\bfseries,
group label node/.append style={left=5mm},
bar label node/.append style={left=5mm},
]{1}{10}
    \gantttitle{Cronograma de actividades semanales}{10} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,10}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup{Objetivo 1}{1}{1} \\
    \ganttbar{Actividad 1}{1}{1} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Actividad 3}{1}{1}\\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Actividad 4}{1}{1}
    \ganttnewline[thick, blue]
\end{ganttchart}
```

[image]